# Storyboard file suddenly missing in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Somehow my storyboard file won't load in my Xcode project. I see the storyboard in the app project from finder, but when I open the Xcode project it's missing and it's red. I tried dragging the file in but it wouldn't show up in Xcode. What's wrong? [image]

Comment: You may have removed the reference by mistake. It's happened to me before. Copy your storyboard elsewhere, clean the project (Opt + Command + Shift + K), delete the file again if necessary (preserve the copy) and throw that copy back in after cleaning. You should be good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your directory structure changed without updating the pbxproj file so the filepath is broken. Click on each affect file, open the Utilities pane to the File Inspector, click on the folder icon and select the file in the Finder window that comes up to restore the path.
[image]